# While creating SQL table and entering data into that table i am receiving error message

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO TourEvents(TourName,Month,Day,Year,Fee) VALUES ('East ','Jan',16,2016,200)
```

> Error at line 1:
>       ORA-02291: integrity constraint (S9684921.SYS_C003209195) violated - parent key not found

Can someone please explain to me what I might be doing wrong to get this error message
To create table i have written below code

```
CREATE TABLE TourEvents
(
Month varchar(50)
,Day INT
,Year INT
,Fee INT
,TourName varchar(50)
,CONSTRAINT PK_TourEvents PRIMARY KEY (TourName,Month,Day,Year)
,FOREIGN KEY (TourName) REFERENCES TOURS(TourName)
);
```

I am new to SQL and therefore struggling with constraints a bit. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you created a `TOURS` table? And does it have a `East ` value in its `TourName` column

Comment: Not totally sure its relevant but you are adding a `TourName` column with a value of `'East '` with a space in this query

Answer (score 1):

Create the `TOURS` table and insert the record as East in

> TourName

column then execute your insert script

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is trying to insert a value into column `TourName` which doesn't exist in the `TOURS` table.

Value `East` should be in the `TOURS` table as it was used as foreign key.

To better understand foreign key see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity)